# NameError: variable is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

Need some help. I created an empty list to append input of names. However, I keep getting an error "NameError: name 'players' is not defined. It works if I defined players = [] as a global variable but not as a main function. Fyi, I'm not allowed to use a global variable.

```
def existingPlayers(name):
    '''
    Check if player name already exists
    '''
    for player in players:
        if player[0].lower() == name.lower():
            return True
    return False

def getPlayerNames():
    '''
    Get the names of the players. Check if the number of players and 
    player names are valid
    '''
    while True:
        name = input("Enter player name or <ENTER> to exit (min 2, max 4 players):")
        if len(name) == 0:
            if len(players) < 2:
                print(f"Minimum 2 players. Currently, {len(players)} player")
                continue
            else:
                break
        if existingPlayers(name):
            print("Repeated name. Choose another name")
            continue
        players.append([name])
        if len(players) == 4:
            break
def main():
    players = []
    getPlayerNames()
main()
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Well, these functions could still be in a class, and you can use class variables, or add another parameter in your functions that accepts the player list from main.

Comment: My question is how do i append to my empty list, players = [ ]  in the main function

Comment: Are you allowed to use and define a Players class ? this would be a good way to avoid global variables.

Comment: either use a class object, or make the players list an argument of the function.

Comment: i haven't learn class yet. how do i make the list argument?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
def existingPlayers(name, players):
    '''
    Check if player name already exists
    '''
    for player in players:
        if player[0].lower() == name.lower():
            return True
    return False

def getPlayerNames(players):
    '''
    Get the names of the players. Check if the number of players and 
    player names are valid
    '''
    while True:
        name = input("Enter player name or <ENTER> to exit (min 2, max 4 players):")
        if len(name) == 0:
            if len(players) < 2:
                print(f"Minimum 2 players. Currently, {len(players)} player")
                continue
            else:
                break
        if existingPlayers(name, players):
            print("Repeated name. Choose another name")
            continue
        players.append([name])
        if len(players) == 4:
            break
def main():
    players = []
    getPlayerNames(players)
main()
```

Comment: it works, but now the code accepts repeated name, which it isn't suppose to

Comment: Ok it's fixed test it again